# How to parse nested json in snowflake using lateral flatten

Tags: google-analytics, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, lateral

WOuld like to extract values from event_params attributes,
I would like to get values from event_params."key": "link_class":string_value
Ex:
event_params--> key=link_class and get "ABC-button loginblue"
I need column name with link_class with "ABC-button loginblue" value in it

```
{
  "app_info": null,
  "collected_traffic_source": null,
  "device": {
    "advertising_id": null,
    "web_info": {
      "browser": "Edge",
      "browser_version": "116.0.1938.76",
      "hostname": "www.ABC.com"
    }
  },
  "ecommerce": null,

  "event_params": [
    {
      "key": "link_class",
      "value": {
        "double_value": null,
        "float_value": null,
        "int_value": null,
        "string_value": "ABC-button loginblue"
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "page_title",
      "value": {
        "double_value": null,
        "float_value": null,
        "int_value": null,
        "string_value": "Welcome  Forward | XYZ Bank"
      }
    }
  ],
  "user_pseudo_id": "899702629.1663712233"
}
select raw,
raw:device.web_info.hostname::string as hostname,
ev.value as event_params
from ANALYTICS_323116990 t ,
lateral flatten (input => t.raw, path =>'event_params') ev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking at GA4's schema on Snowflake?

I wrote a cookbook for that:

- https://medium.com/snowflake/google-analytics-4-in-snowflake-sql-cookbook-d455087882c9

My advice for this schema is to transform that "inconvenient" structure (forced by BigQuery's struct) to something easier to parse.

A JS UDF can help you do this in real-time, or to transform the data into a new table that makes it easier to parse:

```sql
create or replace function parse_ga4_objarray_fixed(V variant)
returns variant
language javascript
AS
$$
var result = {};
for (const x of V) {
  if (x.value){
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(x.value)) {
      if ( key ! = 'set_timestamp_micros') {
        result[x.key] = value;
      }
    }
  } else {
    result[x.key] = null;
  }
}
return result
$$;
```

With that transformation you can query the data in a more natural way:

```sql
SELECT event_timestamp, event_params:value event_value
FROM ga4
WHERE event_name = 'purchase'
AND event_timestamp BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-02';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do I need to parse the event_parm and pass it to the function?
select raw:event_date:: string as event_date,
raw:event_name::string as event_name,
raw:user_pseudo_id:: string as user_pseudo_id,
ev.value
from b,
lateral flatten (input => b.raw, path =>'event_params') ev -- returns 
{
  "key": "page_title",
  "value": {
    "double_value": null,
    "float_value": null,
    "int_value": null,
    "string_value": "Welcome to Banking Forward | ABC Bank"
  }
}. Not sure how to parse it further. If possible would like to get thru lateral flatten

Comment: Now sure how to get "Page_title" with "string_value": "Welcome to Banking Forward | ABC Bank"  from event_params

Comment: Thank you for your parse_ga4_objarray_fixed. It worked for me

Comment: One quick question.

with below json, when ever there is numeric value, the function returns null.
"event_params": [
    {
      "key": "ga_session_number",
      "value": {
        "double_value": null,
        "float_value": null,
        "int_value": 21,
        "string_value": null
      }
    }
Response:--------
 "engaged_session_event": null,
  "engagement_time_msec": null,
  "ga_session_id": null,
  "ga_session_number": null,
  "link_class": "ABC-button loginblue"
Can I get a fix or suggestion how to fix it.

Comment: I just removed if ( key ! = 'set_timestamp_micros') check and added, 
        if (value != null){
            result[x.key] = value;
        }
This works for me now. I am able to get values

Comment: Thanks for JS UDF. This is really cool. 
Please make this small change or better way to do it.